# When Java fullscreen exclusive mode isn't?

Tags: java, user-interface, fullscreen

I am working on an application in fullscreen exclusive mode; in general, this works just fine. On some computers, however, the window is not actually going fullscreen.

All computers are running identical code on Java 6, u45 with Windows 7, 32-bit. On two of them, the app goes fullscreen with no titlebar, no taskbar, etc. and gains keyboard focus. On two other machines, the window, with decorations, enlarges to the size of the screen, does not get keyboard focus, and sometimes minimizes and then maximizes again repeatedly. There are no other processes stealing focus (that I can see), and the computers all have the same processes and services running on them. Also, `isFullScreenSupported()` is returning `true` on all machines.

Any help on this would be helpful; if there are any mysterious processes that might be stealing focus or preventing fullscreen mode, I would love to know what they are.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can play with?

Comment: Check for different graphics adapters / drivers?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I can try, but it'll be a while before I could get it up. The internet computers and the coding computers are on isolated networks.

Comment: @Durandal I'll check. They are different models (although, I think, all Dells).

Comment: I am cautiously optimistic that setting sun.java2d.opengl to false and sun.java2d.d3d to false, plus setting undecorated to true, has corrected the issue.

Comment: As part of the program, I had Pure Data running in the background; apparently the GUI components of PD can steal control on some systems and not others. My only explanation is that there is some interaction between certain devices and TCL (which runs the PD GUI). The solution was to start PD with the -nogui option. I've had no problems on dozens of runs since.